# Matching seconds and millieseconds for audio file length

Tags: c#, regex, ranorex

I am currently working on ranorex to test the audio player , I have a button which will play the audio only for 2 seconds and the it will stopped . Once the audio stopped playing i want to validate the play position in seconds and milliseconds

My range for validation = Success is { 1,994s to 2,006s}
Range for Validation = Fail is { any thing below 1,994s}

I have wrote down the regex for checking that seconds should be either 1 or 2 other than that any thing will cause validation failed
Regex for seconds : ^0([1-2]{1})$

Regex for milliseconds : I want to build a regex which accepts the all number from 994 to 006

Any leads to that

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^0([1-2]{1})$` could be shortened to `^[12]$`, but if you would add digits behind that, due to the character class `[12]` all matches can start with either 1 or 2 and could lead to matching too much.

To match from 1,994 to 2,006 you could make the pattern a bit more specific:

```
^(?:1,99[4-9]|2,00[0-6])$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `1,99[4-9]` match 1,99 and a digit 4-9
  - `|` Or
  - `2,00[0-6]` Match 2,00 and a digit 0-6
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vOMBNQ/1)